# Mootools each function works for last fund in array only

Tags: javascript, arrays, mootools

I got following markup twice on the page with different id for each .option div and it might be duplicate few more times

```
<div class="optionsHolder"></div>

 <div class="option selected">Select</div>
 <div id="option238" class="option">Option1</div>
 <div id="option239" class="option">Option2</div>
 <div id="option261" class="option">Option3</div>
```

I am trying to grab all options and place them inside optionsHolder ,  this works but only for the last optionHolder on the page ,  this is js

```
    var optionscont = $$('.optionsHolder');
    var findoptions = $$('.option');
    optionscont.each(function (element){
        element.adopt(findoptions);
    });
```

any help would be appreciated. thank you!

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/L8PA6/). It's possible that your code that you took this from has a mistake in it. But the snippet you show should work.

Comment: you have multiple optionsHolder's ?, if so are you tring to copy the options into each.  With what u have yes the last optionholder will get alll the options, here a JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cFFSE/ is that what u have?

Comment: @Dampsquid  those are currently 2 menus ,  I am trying to do same foreach ,  grab options from that particular menu and place it inside the holder

Comment: @Marshall  this is exactly what I have and as you can see it does not work for first set http://jsfiddle.net/QqHPR/

Comment: that's because you are looping through each holder. So it will first put them all in the first holder (all of the .options). But will then put them all in the second.

Comment: yes but $$(".options") finds all elements not just the ones between the first holder and the next. It moves them ALL into the first holder then move them ALL into the second. will need a bit more code for what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This i think does what you want [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cFFSE/2/)

```
function GetHolder( option )
{
   var holder = option.getPrevious( ".optionsHolder"  )

   if( holder )
   {
       holder.adopt( option );
   }        
}

var findoptions = $$('.option');
Array.each( findoptions, function( item) { GetHolder( item ) } );
```

Comment: thnx for the try but on the fiddle you posted <div class="optionsHolder"></div>   is still empty , it should hold the options

Comment: im getting el not definded for findoptions.each( GetHolder( el ) );  but I think I know why , my markup is js generated var optionholder = new Element('div').addClass('optionsHolder').inject($(this.optionsContainer))  and looks like your function fires before

Comment: thats old fiddle pls look at new one

Comment: i see that works but for some reason Im still getting same result , markup is same and js also, but oly last holder grabs own elements

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8091/discussion-between-dampsquid-and-benn)

Comment: that is it , I just had to run it on doomready instead of my script since this is a class for selects, thank you!